# Java : 80 bit number ( looking for nice approach )

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, data-structures

I need to generate 80 bit random number ( non non repetitive ) in java.

How can I do that ?

I am planning to do that using current timestamps.this gives me 8 bytes and rest for 2 bytes. I can add something else....please let me know your comments and how can I do that...

Or if you have any other idea to implement the same...

Please consider a System Restart Case

Comment: what does non non
repetitive mean

Comment: "non repetitive" means the generated number should not be the one which is already generated.

Comment: So by "non non repetitive" you mean that duplicates are fine, right?

Comment: using the time stamp won't help unless you pause long enough to let time advance.

Comment: Quick thought - generate a random number of 2 bytes long, get the curent timestamp that is 6 bytes long, shift the timestamp 16bits left and `OR` with the random number. Chances of 2 bytes long random numbers generated at the exact same timestamp being equal is very very rare

Comment: How many numbers are you generating? If you use random generator of sufficient quality (e.g. SecureRandom, but not the standard Random class), then with 80 bit numbers on average you'd expect to generate in the order of a trillion (2^40) numbers before you get a duplicate. That's good enough for many applications...

Comment: at  prajeesh kumar : This is exactly what i was thinking....Please suggest...can i use this approach

Comment: @VJS saw your comment only now. You can use that approach safely, and if you need to make it even safer and you dont have that much volume of this operation, then create a synchronized method which will return the current timestamp and call that method for it. This will ensure that not two objects get the same timestamp

Answer (score 3):

Try using a combination of [`Random#nextBytes(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBytes%28byte%5b%5d%29) and [`new BigInteger(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28byte%5b%5d%29):

```java
Random rand = new Random();
BigInteger r = new BigInteger(80, rand);
// or
byte bs[10];
rand.nextBytes(bs);
BigInteger r80bits = new BigInteger(bs);
```

**[Edit]** It sounds like you're more interested in uniqueness than randomness, especially having little chance of ever using the same number, in which case a timestamp might be more useful.  Here's a way to achieve that, more or less:

```java
public static byte[] get80UniqueBits() {
  // Put eight very likely unique bytes.
  ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(10);
  buf.putLong(System.nanoTime());
  // And two random bytes for good measure.
  byte bytes[] = {0, 0};
  new Random().nextBytes(bytes);
  buf.put(bytes, 0, 2);
  return buf.array();
}
```

Note that the last two bytes aren't strictly necessary.

Comment: you've got bits and bytes mixed up

Comment: @maerics : it is having a possibility of duplicates of numbers.That is why i thought to take the timestamp so that number duplicates should not occurs.

Comment: *BUT* the standard Random implementation has a period of 2^48. Consider using SecureRandom if you actually want 80 bits of randomness.

Comment: @VJS: so you mean that none of the bytes in the byte array should have the same value?  You could just modify my example to replace any repeated values with ones known not to exist in the array.

Comment: at Neil Coffey :  what if my system restarts ?? it will not work.......this is y i thought of something like getting current time date and adjust that in 80 bits....time and date will always be changed so number wont be repeat again anytime.....even after system restart..

Answer (score 1):

A timestamp isn't really random in the sense you mean. It isn't really even pseudo-random in the sense that it always increases.

If you want an 80-bit generator, I've implemented something like that before, though with smaller output from the generator function.

You basically use `nextLong` to get your 64 bit random value. Then you copy bits from there to the other 16 bit positions.

The way you get round seeing a 64-bit cycle is that the bit positions you copy (the "bitset") are different each iteration, and there are a prime number of iterations (11, 31, 97, ...).

So, for example, on iteration 0, you may copy bits 1, 7, 9, 11, 3, ... 12 to the other 16 bit positions. On the next iteration , you'll copy a different set of bits.

That way, when the real generator cycles around, you'll most likely be at a different bit set (due to its prime size) and they won't repeat.

Of course, a better solution would be to find a genuine 80-bit generator - I'm just offering this as a solution to get thing going fast. Unless you're a cryptographer or a statistician, it will be fine (but then again, so would a 64-bit generator called twice with the values shifted and combined, probably).

Comment: i meant to say that.....like i am getting current time date and adjust that in 80 bits....time and date will always be changed so number wont be repeat again anytime.....even after system restart....

Comment: @VJS: if you saw the sequence 1,7,9,15,18,22,45,89,123, would you consider that a desent random sequence? I wouldn't since it is by its nature always increasing in value. You could morph the date/time, such as xoring it with some value in such a way to make it non-increasing, but the date and time as-is wouldn't be very good. If that morphing is what you meant by "adjust that in 80 bits", then it's probably okay.

Answer (score 0):

```
Random generator = new Random();
new BigInteger(80, generator);
```

If you don't want duplicates of numbers, there is not, and will never be, any way to avoid it except explicitly maintaining a `Set` of previously seen numbers and checking against that `Set`.